# finding image position in landscape and portrait in UIWebView when orientation changes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which loads images on it. Obviously on portrait the image will have a different origin x and y point and width and height comparing to the landscape. Question is how do I find this origin x and y when orientation changes? Do I have to inject a js function that finds this number everytime the orientation change or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If you center your image inside of the `UIWebView`, then make the `UIWebView` auto-resize so it takes the full available width, you have no need to use JS to know how large the image is.

I don't know if this suggestion applies to your specific case, I hope it does. Otherwise, please provide more details.

Comment: well the goal is basically to find the x and y coordinate of an image. I basically want to know what is the x and y top left corner coordinate of the image when it is in portrait and as well in landscape. And the image is not necessarily centered. I will use this coordinate for some other calculation in my code

Comment: then you have to inject some JS... have a look at this site for how to find the position of any html element: http://blog.firetree.net/2005/07/04/javascript-find-position/

Comment: do you think if I already know the x and y position of the image in portrait mode, I will be able to find the x and y position of the image when rotated in landscape?

Comment: it depends on how you want to display the image in landscape view... which property do you want to preserve?